Error when running python executable created with Pyinstaller
I created an executable from a python file. It runs normally in my computer but when I try to execute it in another computer I receive an error message .
"UnicodeDecode Error:'utf-8'codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 242420:invalid start byte.
It looks like the error is originated in the line 41 as below:
df1 = pd.read_csv(x,low_memory=False,header=None,names = [f'col{i+1}' for i in range(55)])
I am unable to figure out the error and I haven't tried anything since.
